# Is there a way to adjust for integer overflow?

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I'm noodling through an anagram hash function, already solved several different ways, but I'm looking for extreme performance as an exercise.  I already submitted a solution that passed all the given tests (beating out 100% of all competitors by at least 1ms), but I believe that although it "won", it has a weakness that just wasn't triggered.  It is subject to integer overflow in a way that could affect the results.

The gist of the solution was to combine multiple commutative operations, each taking some number of bits, and concatenate them into one long variable.  I chose xor, sum, and product.  The xor operation cleanly fits within a fixed number of bits.  The sum operation might overflow, but because of the way overflow is addressed, it would still arrive at the same result if letters and their corresponding values are rearranged.  I wouldn't worry, for example, about whether this function would overflow.

```
private short sumHash(String s) {
    short hash=0;
    for (char c:s.toCharArray()) {
        hash+=c;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Where I run into trouble is in the inclusion of products.  If I make a function that returns the product of a list of values (such as character values in a String), then, at the very least, the result could be rendered inaccurate if the product overflowed to exactly zero.

```
private short productHash(String s) {
    short hash=1;
    for (char c:s.toCharArray()) {
        hash*=c;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Is there any safe and performant way to avoid this weakness so that the function gains the benefit of the commutative property of multiplication to produce the same value for anagrams, but can't ever encounter a product that overflows to zero?

Comment: You say the hash function becomes "inaccurate" on 0. Can you be more specific what accuracy you're talking about here? In particular, are you expecting equal hashes to imply equal anagrams? Because that's impossible since there are more anagrams than integers ...

Comment: One solution is to use modulo multiplication. In multiplication `mod p`, cummutativity is preserved if `p` is prime. And modulo will allow you to establish an upper bound to prevent overflow.

Comment: @menton Yes.  Much like the use of cryptographic hashes as digital signatures, I'm happy enough with a highly probable outcome, knowing that "impossible" isn't ruled out.

Comment: @menton I'm requiring equal anagrams to always produce equal hashes.  I acknowledge that other values that are not the same anagram can also produce the same hash value.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks, this seems the simplest approach.  I can use 4294967161L for the prime, use a long to perform the calculations, and fit the result within an int.  Happy to credit you for this if you want to put your solution in an answer.

Comment: @phatfingers Be careful that it isn't too large so you don't overflow before doing the mod operation.

Comment: Also made this into a full-fledged answer.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a good venue for this kind of question

Comment: @phatfingers You should post your solution as an answer below rather than editing your question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'll just remove it then.  It doesn't specifically answer my question about overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only hit zero if

```
a * b = 0 mod 2^64
```

which is equivalent to there being an integer k such that

```
a * b = k * 2^64
```

That is, we get in trouble if factors divide 2^64, i.e. if factors are even. Therefore, the easiest solution is ensuring that all factors are odd, for instance like this:

```
for (char ch : chars) {
  hash *= (ch << 1) | 1;
}
```

This allows you to keep 63 bits of information.

Note however that this technique will only avoid collisions caused by overflow, but not collisions caused by multipliers that share a common factor. If you wish to avoid that, too, you'll need coprime multipliers, which is easiest achieved if they are prime.

Comment: Combined with addition and xor, this technique produced no non-anagram collisions when tested against the first billion integers mapped to the alphabet as base-26 numbers.  By comparison, using modular arithmetic found 68 non-anagram pairs (and their permutations) with the same hash value.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if you're willing to go to some lengths to do it.  The simplest solution that occurs to me is to write

```
hash *= primes[c];
```

where `primes` is an array that maps each possible character to a distinct odd  prime.  Overflowing to zero can only happen if the "true" product in infinite-precision arithmetic is a multiple of 2^32, and if you're multiplying by odd primes, that's impossible.

(You do run into the problem that the hash itself will always be odd, but you could shift it right one bit to obtain a more fully mixed hash.)

Comment: If one hard-coded the list of primes, it would certainly look bulky, but is arguably the most performant way to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The naive way to avoid overflow, is to use a larger type such as `int` or `long`. However, for your purposes, modulo arithmetic might make more sense. You can do `(a * b) % p` for a prime `p` to maintain commutativity. (There is some deep mathematics here called Group Theory, if you are interested in learning more.) You will need to limit `p` to be small enough that each `a * b` does not overflow. The easiest way to do this is to pick a `p` so that `(p - 1)^2` can still be represented in a `short` or whatever data type you are using.

Comment: I agree.  There are even valid English words for which the product of ASCII values for each letter would overflow a `long long`.  Suppose I want to fit the result in an int.  Would it be appropriate to use `(1<<31)-1` for `p` and perform intermediate calculations using a long?

Comment: @phatfingers That might work. You could also do `(a % p) * (b % p) %p` if `a` and `b` can ever be larger than `p` individually.

Comment: @phatfingers Are there any limitations on the allowed characters? If you are only allowing alphabetic characters, for example, you could map them to 1 through 26 which greatly reduces the magnitude of repeated products compared to using the ascii values.

Comment: It's common to see anagram problems limited to 26 characters, but even so, it would still be easy to overflow a long at 5 bits per character vs. 7 bits per character.

Comment: If `a` is a character and `b` is the `running total % p`, then each individual `a` and `b` are safe.

Comment: @phatfingers I agree that `b` is guaranteed to be safe, because you already `% p` it. For your choice of `p = 1 << 31 - 1`, `a` is fine as well. I mentioned the alternative calculation in case you need to choose a smaller `p` which might be smaller than some character ascii values.

Comment: I appreciate it, although for reasons I don't understand yet, modular arithmetic seems to allow some consistent collision pairs, such as, `bbllnn cciipp` and `ddllww ffiixx` for a variety of large p values.

Comment: @phatfingers I saw your comment on the other answer. It would be interesting to dig into those collisions a little more. I'm willing to bet there's a good explanation in the underlying math.